# Remove space from field where character exists

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can I remove spaces from a field in a table if the field contains a specific character I have tried the query below but get the error 'Subquery returned more than 1 value, this is not permitted when the subquery follows =.......'

```
UPDATE mytable
SET myfield = REPLACE(myfield, ' ', '')
WHERE (CHARINDEX('[', myfield) > 0)
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you referring to?

Comment: [**But, your query works fine here?**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4cb67/1)

Comment: Where is your subquery, is this the actual/full query?

Comment: Sorry!  I was testing the query in a local sqlexpress table and the primary Key was not set thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Test(
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     name varchar(30)
    );
INSERT INTO Test(name) VALUES('  [ i k i p e d i a  '),('  W i k i p e d i a  ');

UPDATE Test SET name = REPLACE(name, ' ', '') WHERE name LIKE '%[%';
```

Querying gives,

```
SELECT * FROM Test
ID  NAME
1   [ikipedia
2   W i k i p e d i a
```